# Runtime property override in order to fetch historical data

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm currently finishing work on object change log functionality and would like to polish few things. Since we have a lot of web forms/reports where historical data should appear, I'm wondering if there is a way to implement that without changing controls/reports.
Currently, I have this situation:

```cs
public class Foo {
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set;}

    public string GetHistoricalValue(string propertyName) 
    {
        HistoryHelper historyHelper = CreateHistoryHelper(this);
        return historyHelper.GetHistoricalValue(propertyName, CreatedDate);
    }
...

public class HistoryHelper {
    public string GetHistoricalValue(string propertyName, DateTime date) {
    ...
```

So, when someone wants to fetch historical data for Property1:

```cs
string historicalValue = fooInstance.GetHistoricalValue("Property1");
```

It's obvious that this approach requires a lot of changes in current application. 
Is there a way to make Foo class returns historical value when I access Property1 in regular way:

```cs
string historicalValue = fooInstance.Property1;
```

Something like dynamically generating subclass with overriden properties or some other solution?
Is this possible?

Comment: Why you don't want to use something like the method `GetProperty1(DateTime when)` in `Foo`? And what exactly does the phrase "this approach requires a lot of changes in current application" mean?

Comment: @Mikhail Report fields and web controls are bound to certain property name. I need to either change all controls/reports where I need history data or override those properties when I need historical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### INITIAL ANSWER

Something like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public bool HistoricalMode { get; set; }

    private string _property1;
    public string Property1 { 
        get { 
            if (HistoricalMode) {
                return GetHistoricalValue("Property1");
            } else {
                return _property1;
            }
        set {
            if (HistoricalMode){
                throw new NotSupportedException("Updates not possible in historical mode.");
            } else {
                _property1 = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { 
        get {
            // Similar pattern as above
        }
        set {
            // Similar pattern as above
        }
    }

    public string GetHistoricalValue(string propertyName) {
        HistoryHelper historyHelper = CreateHistoryHelper(this);
        return historyHelper.GetHistoricalValue(propertyName, CreatedDate);
    }
}
```

Basically the idea is to keep a boolean in your objects which indicates in the object is in 'history mode'. If so, use your helper method. If not, normal properties getters/setters apply.

### UPDATE

The solution to this question I think would require a change in your framework (if you have a single framework for all your applications). I would seek the solution in the way you are loading your objects. Hopefully you can detect when an object is required in 'historical mode' and when in 'normale mode'. Where you now 'just read' the object (record) from the database, in historical mode you need to compose the original object (from when the change happened) from your change log functionality. That way, all your current application can (hopefully) stay the way they are. The 'only' change you need to do is at the repository class.

This is all just speculation btw.

Comment: This is something that I would like to achieve, but without changing existing classes. Change log functionality needs to be integrated into cca. 15 existing apps. Every one of them has around 70-100 domain classes. Can I generate Foo subclass and all needed property overrides on the fly?

Comment: Not really. Existing properties would have to be virtual to be overriden, which I doubt they are. Also, you would need your repository/dal/... to return the subclasses instead of the existing classes, which I cannot judge from your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answers/observations. Never the less I decided to go simpler way than I intended initially. I will add another function to HistoryHelper which will modify current object with historical data. Something like this: `HistoryHelper.ApplyHistoricalData(fooInstance)`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you easily affect how `Foo` instances are created? If so, you can for example create  derived `class HistoricalFoo : Foo`, make `Property1` virtual and use its getter to change its behaviour. Then use `HistoricalFoo` whenever you need historical data. It is not a very clean object model, but can get the job done.

```
public class Foo
{
    protected string _property1;
    public virtual string Property1
    {
        get { return _property1; }
        set { _property1 = value; }
    }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set;}

    /* ... */
}

public class HistoricalFoo : Foo
{
    public override string Property1
    {
        get
        {
            return GetHistoricalValue("Property1");
        }
    }
}
```

If this is not applicable, it's possible to embed some decision logic into the `Property1` getter. In this scenario, you would have to change the internal state of the `Foo` instance - for example by setting a boolean flag `IsInHistoryMode`. Changing object states can be very tricky though, expecially in multithreaded environment.

```
public class Foo
{
    public bool IsInHistoryMode { get; set; }

    protected string _property1;
    public virtual string Property1
    {
        get
        {
            if(IsInHistoryMode)
            {
                return GetHistoricalValue("Property1");
            }

            return _property1;
        }
        set
        {
            _property1 = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set;}

    /* ... */
}
```